# Managing python versions on conda environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've recently created a new environment following conda's instructions.
I currently installed anaconda3 with python3 as the default in my pc, but now I need to run python2 code so I created the virtual env as:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

But even inside py27, when I run `python` it uses python3 and not python2.

Is there a way I can change de behavior of the `python` command so it defults to python2 but *only* in my py27 virtual environment?

Thanks

Comment: Show how you run Python, starting from when you first turn on cmd and activate your environment.

Comment: yes, some more information should be helpful. Also, what's the value of $PATH? You can definitely do what you are trying to do. If you get stuck, a hacky workaround would be to call full python to python inside the environment. e.g. /path_to_conda/envs/py27/bin/python my_code.py

Comment: I switch to my environment with

conda activate py27

And my $PATH variable is:

bash: /home/tomas/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin:/home/tomas/anaconda3/bin:/home/tomas/bin:/home/tomas/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: I run ptyhon using: python example.py, but that defaults to python3 even in my py27 environment. So i'm currently running programs as: python2 example.py